# Basic Auth login Popup not showing

Tags: reactjs, express, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401

I am attempting to generate the Basic auth login popup when clicking logout. 
The 401 is being sent but no popup is appearing.
Frontend

```
 handleLogout = () => {
    fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/logout`)

  }

<Button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</Button>
```

Backend

```
  app.use('/logout', function(req, res) {
    res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  });
```

The response in the network headers

```
Response Headers

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Vary: Origin
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=Authorization Required
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Comment: _no popup is appearing_ Because you are not showing the popup! You need to do something after `fetch` like `fetch().then().catch()`

Comment: @AnandUndavia is right, you can redirect after the fetch to the logout popup. Also i would maybe use a `200` status code instead of a `401`. 401 is the code for unauthorized (which the user isn't im assuming).